# What is the most basic window manager for ubuntu that can be used to display a single application

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager

I've tried starting a full screen application without a window manager, using xinit,
which works but instead of starting at the top left of the screen the application starts somewhere in the middle of my screen.

I've tried the same using a custom entry in /usr/share/xsessions 
and starting that from lightdm instead
of the default ubuntu window manager, but that gives me the same result.

I've then added my application to the startup applications of the ubuntu window manager
and that works properly... but I don't want to start the entire desktop

So I'm thinking perhaps a simple window manager will allow me to define that my application
should start as soon as it is loaded and that as a result it will be displayed full screen
and starting at the upper left corner of the screen.

So basically a Window Manager that will allow me to disable everything except my application. (And the background should be completely black by default so that the screen is black until my application has finished loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different window managers that can do this.

One is **[Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/)**.

To set the background to black and start the application at the same time as Fluxbox starts, put e.g.

```
/usr/bin/fbsetroot -solid black
myapplication &
```

in `~/.fluxbox/startup` before the `exec /usr/bin/fluxbox` line.

To start the application maximized, see the `~/.fluxbox/apps` file. An entry I use to always start a certain application maximized is:

```
[app] (name=urxvt) (class=URxvt) (title=irssi)
  [Maximized]   {yes}
[end]
```

The format of these files is aptly documented at the project's homepage and wiki.

Fluxbox is more or less fully stylable through themes. By default it has a task bar, but that is removable in the theme file.

Answer (score 4):

## [-geometry](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html#sect6)

According to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_X11/Window_Managers

> One can also use X11 without a window manager. Typically, one writes a
>   session script which starts an "xterm" at a "-geometry" location.
>   Keyboard-oriented users may start a keyboard shortcut daemon like
>   xbindkeys and manage windows through Xresources geometry hints or with
>   tools like xdotool.
>
> See the resources at http://github.com/patrickhaller/no-wm

Perhaps `s/xterm/your-app-name/` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that any tiling window manager would do what you describe.

The first that comes to my mind is [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/), because its default configuration is basically that: black desktop, no window decoration, and a layout that allows you to see your applications maximized by default.

Comment: you're right it doesn't make sense sorry, long day I meant by using xinit directly , no window manager

Comment: Ok, I edited :)